# is there a way I can apply a useContext in this code here?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I was working on a reactjs activity which was to build a a simple calculator, I've already completed activity its just that my prof ask me to use usecontext to practice

```
  const [value, setValue] = useState("0");
  const [prevValue, setPrevValue] = useState("");
  const [operator, setOperator] = useState("");
  const [display, setDisplay] = useState("0");

  const handleButtonClick = useCallback(
    (buttonValue: string) => {
      const utility = parseInt(buttonValue, 10);
      if (!isNaN(utility)) {
        number(buttonValue);
      } else {
        switch (buttonValue) {
          case "C":
            clear();
            break;

          case "+-":
            invertSign();
            break;

          case "%":
            setValue((parseInt(value) / 100).toString());
            break;

          case "=":
            handleEqual();
            break;

          default:
            handleOperator(buttonValue);
            break;
        }
      }
    },
    [value, prevValue, operator]
  );
```

I've tried watching/reading about useContext and i think i've already understand the basics, so what i've tried is to copy the value of "value" in the context and pass the value to the display part of calculator which was completely useless.

```
<input
          type="text"
          value={display ? display : prevValue} // this where the part ive tried passing the context
          disabled
          className="bg-gray-700 h-14 rounded-md w-52 text-right text-white text-4xl"
        />
```

so i just want to ask if there's a way to make all the const usestate into a context so i can import it again(also making it global in the process)in my codes. I also want to ask if there are better part of my code where i can use context. btw im completely new to programming so the ways i understand some things was just a mess.

my whole code btw:

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ButtonStyle from "./component/ButtonStyle";

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("0");
  const [prevValue, setPrevValue] = useState("");
  const [operator, setOperator] = useState("");
  const [display, setDisplay] = useState("0");

  const handleButtonClick = useCallback(
    (buttonValue: string) => {
      const utility = parseInt(buttonValue, 10);
      if (!isNaN(utility)) {
        number(buttonValue);
      } else {
        switch (buttonValue) {
          case "C":
            clear();
            break;

          case "+-":
            invertSign();
            break;

          case "%":
            setValue((parseInt(value) / 100).toString());
            break;

          case "=":
            handleEqual();
            break;

          default:
            handleOperator(buttonValue);
            break;
        }
      }
    },
    [value, prevValue, operator]
  );

  function number(buttonValue: string) {
    if (prevValue !== "" && operator === "") {
      setValue(buttonValue);
      setPrevValue("");
    } else {
      setValue(value === "0" ? buttonValue : value + buttonValue);
    }
  }

  function clear() {
    setValue("0");
    setPrevValue("");
    setOperator("");
  }

  function invertSign() {
    if (prevValue !== "" && value === "") {
      setValue((-1 * parseInt(prevValue)).toString());
      setPrevValue("");
    } else {
      setValue((-1 * parseInt(value)).toString());
    }
  }

  function handleOperator(buttonValue: string) {
    setOperator(buttonValue);
    if (prevValue !== "") {
      handleEqual();
    } else {
      setPrevValue(value);
      setValue(" ");
    }
  }

  function handleEqual() {
    let numPrevValue = parseFloat(prevValue);
    let numValue = parseFloat(value);
    let equal = 0;
    if (operator === "+") {
      equal = numPrevValue + numValue;
    } else if (operator === "-") {
      equal = numPrevValue - numValue;
    } else if (operator === "x") {
      equal = numPrevValue * numValue;
    } else if (operator === "/") {
      equal = numPrevValue / numValue;
    } else if (operator === "") {
      return;
    }

    setPrevValue(equal.toString());
    setOperator("");
    setValue("");
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setDisplay(value);
  }, [value]);

  return (
    <div className="flex items-center justify-center h-screen w-screen bg-yellow-300">
      <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center border-2 border-black bg-gray-800 rounded-md gap-1 p-1">
        <input
          type="text"
          value={display ? display : prevValue}
          disabled
          className="bg-gray-700 h-14 rounded-md w-52 text-right text-white text-4xl"
        />

        <div className="grid grid-cols-4 grid-rows-5 gap-1 w-52">
          {[
            ["C", "+-", "%", "/"],
            ["7", "8", "9", "x"],
            ["4", "5", "6", "-"],
            ["1", "2", "3", "+"],
            ["0", ".", "="],
          ].map((row, rowindex) =>
            row.map((button, buttonindex) => (
              <ButtonStyle
                key={`button-${rowindex}-${buttonindex}`}
                text={button}
                onClick={() => handleButtonClick(button)}
              />
            ))
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm struggling to think what your professor has in mind, because i don't see how context would be at all useful with the code you've shown. Typically, context is used when props is too cumbersome. Ie, if you find yourself having to repeatedly pass a value through multiple components just to get it to some other component (nicknamed "prop drilling"), that's where context can step in. But your code has almost no examples of using props at all, so there's nothing to replace.

Comment: yeah thats what i think too, it left me thinking maybe it can be use on either passing a usestate or passing function.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Context API here would be wrong.

You're not passing any props and state you're storing is very closely tied to the calculator component.

If the assignment isn't required, just don't do it, or if you want to learn it yourself, make a simple app with some nested components and implement a light/dark mode.

If it is required, do the wrong thing and abstract the state of the calculator away from the component here, into some context you build named like `CalculatorContext`. Have the Context store the calculator's state, wrap your component in the context, and your component can then hook into the context to read & write to the (needlessly) higher level state.